# how to add new field in a 'zip' jagged array

Tags: python, jagged-arrays, uproot, awkward-array

I want to add a new field in an already zipped jagged array. For example, if I zip 4D info into a muons object, then I can call pt,eta,phi,charge like this: `muons.Muon.pt`. However, if I want to add a new field such as `2*pt` into this muons object, then I can't do this with `muons.Muon['pt2'] = 2 * arrays['Muon_pt"]`. Is there anything I misunderstand or how can I add a new field in this jagged array? Could you please help me? thanks

```py
muons = ak.zip({
    "pt": arrays["Muon_pt"],
    "eta": arrays["Muon_eta"],
    "phi": arrays["Muon_phi"],
    "charge": arrays["Muon_charge"],
})
```

I think I can add a new field in the zipped jagged array, like: `muons.Muon['pt2']` then I can call this field with `muons.Muon.pt2`

Comment: I see now that your question was cross-posted to https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward/discussions/2017, where Angus found your issue: you said `muons.Muon["pt2"]`, rather than `muons["pt2"]` (and I must have auto-corrected in my head). Also, the GitHub Discussions tend to be more active than StackOverflow for Uproot/Awkward questions; I saw this because I've set up an alert in StackOverflow, but I don't think anyone else who works on these projects has done that.

Comment: ahh, thanks for letting me know, then I will keep this in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is the right way to go about it, and it should work.

As a walkthrough, we first get some `arrays`,

```py
>>> import uproot
>>> import skhep_testdata
>>> import awkward as ak
>>> arrays = uproot.open(skhep_testdata.data_path("uproot-HZZ.root"))["events"].arrays()
```

Then zip them into a structure,

```py
>>> muons = ak.zip({
...     "px": arrays["Muon_Px"],
...     "py": arrays["Muon_Py"],
...     "pz": arrays["Muon_Pz"],
... })
>>> muons.show(type=True)
type: 2421 * var * {
    px: float32,
    py: float32,
    pz: float32
}
[[{px: -52.9, py: -11.7, pz: -8.16}, {px: 37.7, py: 0.693, pz: ..., ...}],
 [{px: -0.816, py: -24.4, pz: 20.2}],
 [{px: 49, py: -21.7, pz: 11.2}, {px: 0.828, py: 29.8, pz: 37}],
 [{px: 22.1, py: -85.8, pz: 404}, {px: 76.7, py: -14, pz: 335}],
 [{px: 45.2, py: 67.2, pz: -89.7}, {px: 39.8, py: 25.4, pz: 20.1}],
 [{px: 9.23, py: 40.6, pz: -14.6}, {px: -5.79, py: -30.3, pz: 43}],
 [{px: 12.5, py: -42.5, pz: -124}, {px: 29.5, py: -4.45, pz: -26.4}],
 [{px: 34.9, py: -16, pz: 156}],
 [{px: -53.2, py: 92, pz: 35.6}, {px: 11.5, py: -4.42, pz: -17.5}],
 [{px: -67, py: 53.2, pz: 54.4}, {px: -18.1, py: -35.1, pz: 58}],
 ...,
 [{px: 14.9, py: 32, pz: -156}],
 [{px: -24.2, py: -35, pz: -19.2}],
 [{px: -9.2, py: -42.2, pz: -64.3}],
 [{px: 34.5, py: 28.8, pz: -151}, {px: -31.6, py: -10.4, pz: -111}],
 [{px: -39.3, py: -14.6, pz: 61.7}],
 [{px: 35.1, py: -14.2, pz: 161}],
 [{px: -29.8, py: -15.3, pz: -52.7}],
 [{px: 1.14, py: 63.6, pz: 162}],
 [{px: 23.9, py: -35.7, pz: 54.7}]]
```

And now add the new field:

```py
>>> muons["px2"] = 2 * arrays["Muon_Px"]
```

By construction, this `px2` has the same number of elements (deeply, for all sublists) as `px`. That should also be true in your `pt` example. So the above line should successfully add the new field; if it doesn't, then I think you want to [submit a bug report](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug+%28unverified%29&template=bug-report.yml).

Here's what the new `muons` looks like for me:

```py
>>> muons.show(type=True)
type: 2421 * var * {
    px: float32,
    py: float32,
    pz: float32,
    px2: float32
}
[[{px: -52.9, py: -11.7, pz: -8.16, px2: -106}, {px: 37.7, py: ..., ...}],
 [{px: -0.816, py: -24.4, pz: 20.2, px2: -1.63}],
 [{px: 49, py: -21.7, pz: 11.2, px2: 98}, {px: 0.828, py: 29.8, ...}],
 [{px: 22.1, py: -85.8, pz: 404, px2: 44.2}, {px: 76.7, py: -14, ...}],
 [{px: 45.2, py: 67.2, pz: -89.7, px2: 90.3}, {px: 39.8, py: 25.4, ...}],
 [{px: 9.23, py: 40.6, pz: -14.6, px2: 18.5}, {px: -5.79, py: -30.3, ...}],
 [{px: 12.5, py: -42.5, pz: -124, px2: 25.1}, {px: 29.5, py: -4.45, ...}],
 [{px: 34.9, py: -16, pz: 156, px2: 69.8}],
 [{px: -53.2, py: 92, pz: 35.6, px2: -106}, {px: 11.5, py: -4.42, ...}],
 [{px: -67, py: 53.2, pz: 54.4, px2: -134}, {px: -18.1, py: -35.1, ...}],
 ...,
 [{px: 14.9, py: 32, pz: -156, px2: 29.8}],
 [{px: -24.2, py: -35, pz: -19.2, px2: -48.3}],
 [{px: -9.2, py: -42.2, pz: -64.3, px2: -18.4}],
 [{px: 34.5, py: 28.8, pz: -151, px2: 69}, {px: -31.6, py: -10.4, ...}],
 [{px: -39.3, py: -14.6, pz: 61.7, px2: -78.6}],
 [{px: 35.1, py: -14.2, pz: 161, px2: 70.1}],
 [{px: -29.8, py: -15.3, pz: -52.7, px2: -59.5}],
 [{px: 1.14, py: 63.6, pz: 162, px2: 2.28}],
 [{px: 23.9, py: -35.7, pz: 54.7, px2: 47.8}]]
```

`px2` has been added to the record type and you can see it in the values. This is Uproot 5 and Awkward Array 2, by the way, but this should also have worked in the previous major version.